# YiiBooster radioButtonListRow not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using YiiBooster with Yii to produce a form.

Most of the form works - typeahead, checkbox and input rows are all fine. When I try to use a radioButtonListRow, it renders the template text (*{labelTitle}{endLabel}*), instead of the text for my labels:

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonListRow(
            $model,
            'radioButtons',
            array(
                'Option one',
                'Option two',
            )
        ); ?>
```

results in the html

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Surveys_radioButtons">GCSE Maths</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="ytSurveys_radioButtons" type="hidden" value="" name="Surveys[radioButtons]">
            <span id="Surveys_radioButtons">
            <input id="Surveys_radioButtons_0" value="0" type="radio" name="Surveys[radioButtons]">
            {labelTitle}{endLabel}
            <input id="Surveys_radioButtons_1" value="1" type="radio" name="Surveys[radioButtons]">
            {labelTitle}{endLabel}
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The example above is copied directly from the [YiiBooster examples](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms/view/activeform.html), with just the property name changed.

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I compared implementations of `CHtml::radioButtonList` and I think the problem is in yii version.
Just update it to the newest and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it to

```
<?php 
echo $form->radioButtonListGroup(
         $model,
         'radioButtons',
         array(
             'Option one',
             'Option two',
         )
     );
?>
```